# Wordpress - Only allow one Text Widget to be added

Tags: wordpress

I'm in the process of trying to create a custom theme for Wordpress and managed to create a working widget area. But for the purpose of this theme, I would like to allow only one "Text-Widget" to be used. How would I go about limiting this?

Answer (score 0):

Be specific about what you want to ask. Wordpress don't limit widgets you can use as much text widget.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide urls so we could advice a solution to you?
I'll update the code below to be compatible with your theme if you can give a url to your blog.

WordPress don't allow you to limit the number of widgets but you can use javascript to hide the next sidebar items.

```
$('.sidebar li:gt(0)').hide();
```

the 2nd list item onwards will be hidden.

and yeah, this is a bit of cheating though.
SEO wise the next widgets are still visible.